# What is the Ubuntu live-updateable state?

Tags: system-installation

I installed Ubuntu desktop from a USB stick to my PC hard-drive.
I had some weird error on install and searched for solution.
Solution was to click the tab key at the colon prompt and type live-updatable (live- something like update, I believe).
Now I want to install Shotwell and I get the following error:
"do not know how to install app in state updatable-live"
How do I get from the state I'm in to a regular install?
Cheers,
Sean.

Comment: A Live environment cannot be 'converted' to a real install. You must install Ubuntu (for real) on the media. Backup your data, since the install will wipe *everything*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I found that actually Shotwell was already installed.  Everything seems to run OK, even after reboot.  I guess I don't know what to do, as I will be faced with the same install options at the colon prompt; live, live-updatable, menu, help, etc.  I don't know what to choose, and I can't find any real documentation on what the choice should be. Like the difference between live, live-updatable, etc, and why I should choose one over the other if I want to install Ubuntu.  What will any other option give me that's different to what I have now?

Comment: I just looked at my Google search history.  The error I got when trying to do the Ubuntu install was "gfxboot.c32 not a com32r image".  I read that I should type the tab key.  At the boot: prompt I then typed live-install.  The other options are live, check, memtest, mainmenu, help.  I chose live-install since I want to install Ubuntu.  Should I have chosen another option? Is there any documentation for this install process?